# PDFs opening in Chromium despite Acrobat being set as default

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium, virus-removal

This is some really weird behaviour.

I have set Adobe Acrobat as my default app for opening PDFs.

But as you can see in the screenshot the acrobat icon is not there. [image: As you can see below].

And when I actually double click on the icon it opens in something called Chromium, whose interface looks like this[image]

And when I click on the icon in the top right and the click 'About Chromium' I get this
[image]

I can't work out how to uninstall the program because it is not listed in my list of programs in the control panel or in the list of programs in the start menu.

**What is going on?** On some sites it says Chromium is legitimate, on others that it is a virus.

Is Chromium a virus? My computer seems to think Acrobat is the default app for opening PDFs but it always opens them in this thing called Chromium. And chromium is not listed anywhere as a program so I can't uninstall it.

And, if it is a virus **how do I get rid of it?**

Comment: Please clarify if your computer belongs to a company (or is private but enrolled in a company device management system). It says in the screenshot "your browser is managed" which usually indicates a corporate policy controls the computer. If that is the case talk to your system administrator.

Comment: Chromium is a browser from the same family as Chrome, Opera, Edge, etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering @Tonny. It is a private computer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Reddy Lutonadio. So any idea how I get my PDFs to open in acrobat?

Comment: Go to Settings > Apps > Default apps > Choose default apps by file type. Find pdf, and try changing it Acrobat

Comment: Thanks @Reddy Lutonadio, but I did that already. One of the reasons I posted here is that I found that solution. Acrobat is set to be the default app for .pdf file suffixes according to windows but click on a pdf and Chromium still opens it! It's maddening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution to this was to disable HP Sure Click (which was what the small blue icon discussed above was). Sure Click was rerouting any unverified pdfs from email or the internet to Chromium. You can either disable this protection on a case-by-case basis by right-clicking the file and then selecting 'Remove protection', or you can simply disable the entire HP Sure Click app.

Comment: Congrats on solving this. You can mark your answer as accepted. This will make sure your answer is displayed over other ones and the question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium is an open source webbrowser.
The main part of it (the "engine") is also used by Google Chrome, Opera and the latest version of Microsoft Edge. (And there are a bunch of Linux browsers as well that are based on Chromium.
So Chromium is not a virus.

What has happened is, that at some point, someone set Chromium as the default PDF handler on your computer. (All modern browsers, including the Chromium based ones, can be used as PDF reader too.)
You may have done this yourself or whatever program that installed Chromium did that for you.

To switch it back to Adobe you need to tell Windows that you want to use Adobe. This is NOT a setting you can change in Chromium or in Adobe. It is a Windows setting.

Open the Settings, find the "Default Apps by File Type" section.
On the left-hand side look for .pdf in the list. It should show Chromium on the right. Click on Chromium to change that to Adobe (or any other program that can handle PDF, you will be shown a list).

Comment: First screenshot shows that Adobe Reader is already associated with PDF files. Maybe the handler is broken...?

Comment: That's why it should be set again. I wonder what that blue overlay icon is all about. That isn't standard.

Comment: Windows doesn't associate extensions directly to EXEs. It stores "opener definitions" (I don't know the technical term) and associations between extensions and these definitions. I think Adobe Reader's definition was somehow hijacked by Chromium and resetting it may not work.

Comment: @gronostaj That could be. But if that is the case there is a bigger problem: Chromium by itself wouldn't do that. There has to be some form of malware on the system.

Comment: Malware that sneakily installs Chromium and sets it to open PDFs? I doubt that Chromium has such zealous fanboys who would create this worm ;) [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor). It's probably just a badly scripted installer. Happened to me in the past with some different program.

Comment: @gronostaj The circumstances are but too specific for a random installer error I would stay. Seems rather deliberate. You don't hijack a file-type handler by accident.

Comment: Oh, you totally do if you don't know how Windows file associations work. I've literally had one installer do it. If I were to do something malicious, I'd come up with something more sinister than changing the PDF reader.

Comment: Thanks @Tonny. I have done that already. One of the reasons I posted here is that that solution did not work. Went to default apps by file type, scrolled down to .pdf. It was already on Acrobat. It's a really pernicious problem. Even when I try to open a pdf *within Acrobat* (via File-Open) it reroutes to Chromium. Honestly I suspect malware. It's such unusual behaviour.

Comment: And @Tonny that blue overlay icon is the Chromium symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Chromium is a web browser that is a basis for Chrome and others. Here's a [Wikipedia article on Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)). It's safe.

I suppose Chromium somehow hijacked Adobe Reader's PDF handler and now when a file gets associated to Adobe Reader, Chromium's executable is used to open it.

Try to uninstall Adobe Reader and install it again. Hopefully this will recreate file associations and handlers.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated on the comments and previous answers, Chromium is a web browser and not a virus.

One more thing you can try is to set Acrobat as default reader via its settings. Open Acrobat, on the menu, click Edit > Preferences. Click on General. On the right pane, go to the bottom, click on "Select as Default PDFs Handler". Follow the instructions.

At least for now, also check "Tell me if Adobe Acrobat Reader is not my default PDF application" for Acrobat to warn when it is not the default app to open PDF files.